# Error in factor(dataset$Name, levels = c("Zach Wilson:Jaylen Gipson"), : invalid 'labels'; length 269 should be 1 or 1

Tags: r, linear-regression, categorical-data

I am running a regression on my dataset that has 269 rows. I have two categories. They are "Name" and "Team". I need to know the onehot encoding process to code this categorical data. The previous answers have not answered questions on how to hot encode categorical with large datasets into a binary variable

This is what I run:

```
dataset$Name = factor(dataset$Name,
                       levels = c('Zach Wilson:Jaylen Gipson'),
                       labels = c(1:269))
```

This is my error:

```
Error in factor(dataset$Name, levels = c("Zach Wilson:Jaylen Gipson"),  : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 269 should be 1 or 1
```

---

```
dput(head(dataset))

ture(list(ï..Name = structure(c(269L, 222L, 76L, 185L, 10L, 
    253L), .Label = c("Aaron Allen", "Adrian Martinez", "Aidan O'Connell", 
    "Alan Bowman", "Anderson Castle", "Andrew Marty", "Andrew Peasley", 
    "Anthony Richardson", "Anthony Russo", "Asher O'Hara", "Austin Aune", 
    "Austin Kendall", "Bailey Hockman", "Bailey Zappe", "Baylor Romney", 
    "Ben Brittain", "Ben Bryant", "Ben Finley", "Ben Wooldridge", 
    "Blaise Bentsen", "Bo Nix", "Brady McBride", "Brady White", "Brandon Peters", 
    "Braxton Burmeister", "Brayden Stringer", "Brendon Clark", "Brennan Armstrong", 
    "Breylin Smith", "Brian Maurer", "Brock Purdy", "Bryce Young", 
    "Bryson Lucero", "Cade Ballard", "Cade Fennegan", "Cade Fortin", 
    "Cade McNamara", "Caleb Lynum", "Calvin Brownholtz", "Carson Baker", 
    "Carson Strong", "Casey Thompson", "Chance Lovertich", "Chandler Fields", 
    "Chandler Morris", "Charlie Brewer", "Chase Brice", "Chase Cunningham", 
    "Chase Wolf", "Chevan Cordeiro", "Chris Ferguson", "Chris Katrenick", 
    "Chris Reynolds", "Christian Anderson", "Chubba Purdy", "Clayton Tune", 
    "Colby Suits", "Cole Snyder", "Collin Hill", "Coltin Clack", 
    "Connor Bazelak", "Coran Taylor", "Cornelious Brown", "D'Eriq King", 
    "D'Wan Mathis", "D.J. Uiagalelei", "Dakota Allen", "Dalen Morris", 
    "Darius Ocean", "Davis Beville", "Davis Brin", "Dennis Grosel", 
    "Desmond Ridder", "Desmond Trotter", "Devin Leary", "Dillon Gabriel", 
    "Dom Shoffner", "Drew Pyne", "Emory Jones", "Ethan Bullock", 
    "Evan Conley", "Evan Prater", "Feleipe Franks", "Frank Harris", 
    "Fred Payton", "Garrett Greene", "Garrett Shrader", "Gavin Hardison", 
    "Gerry Bohanon", "Graham Mertz", "Grant Loy", "Grant Wells", 
    "Grayson McCall", "Gunnar Hoak", "Gunnar Holmberg", "Gunnar Watson", 
    "Haaziq Daniels", "Hajj-Malik Williams", "Hank Bachmeier", "Hank Gibbs", 
    "Harrison Bailey", "Haynes King", "Hendon Hooker", "Henry Colombi", 
    "Holton Ahlers", "Hudson Card", "Hunter Dekkers", "Hunter Helms", 
    "Ian Book", "Ira Armstead", "Isaiah Bravo", "Isaiah Williams", 
    "Ja'Quinden Jackson", "Jace Ruder", "Jack Abraham", "Jack Miller", 
    "Jack Sears", "Jacob Free", "Jacob Huesman", "Jacobian Morgan", 
    "Jacolby Criswell", "Jake Haener", "Jalon Daniels", "James Blackman", 
    "James Graham", "Jarret Doege", "Jarrett Guarantano", "Jarrett Guest", 
    "Jason Bean", "Jason Shelley", "Jawon Pass", "Jaylen Gipson", 
    "Jeff Sims", "Jemel Jones", "Jeremy Hunt", "Jimmy Holiday", "Joe Milton", 
    "Joey Gatewood", "Joey Yellen", "John Rhys Plumlee", "Johnathan Bennett", 
    "Johnny Langan", "Jordan McCloud", "Jordan Travis", "Jordan Weeks", 
    "Jordan Yates", "Josh Adkins", "Josiah Johnson", "JoVoni Johnson", 
    "JT Shrout", "Justin Fields", "Justin Rogers", "Justin Tomlin", 
    "K.J. Costello", "Kason Martin", "Katravis Marsh", "Kaylan Wiggins", 
    "Kaymen Cureton", "Kellen Mond", "Ken Seals", "Kenny Pickett", 
    "Kenyon Oblad", "Keon Howard", "Kevaris Thomas", "Keytaon Thompson", 
    "KJ Jefferson", "Kyle Trask", "Lance LeGendre", "Layne Hatcher", 
    "Levi Lewis", "Levi Williams", "Lindell Stone", "Logan Bonner", 
    "Logan Holgorsen", "Lowell Narcisse", "Luke Anthony", "Luke McCaffrey", 
    "Luke Zban", "Maasai Maynor", "Mac Jones", "Malik Cunningham", 
    "Malik Hornsby", "Malik Willis", "Mason Garcia", "Matt Corral", 
    "Matt Robinson", "Matthew Downing", "Max Bortenschlager", "Max Duggan", 
    "Max Gilliam", "Max Johnson", "Michael Kern", "Michael Lindauer", 
    "Michael Penix", "Michael Pratt", "Mike Collins", "Mike DiLiello", 
    "Mike Fallon", "Mike Wright", "Mikele Colasurdo", "Miles Kendrick", 
    "Mitch Griffis", "Myles Brennan", "N'Kosi Perry", "Nick Ast", 
    "Nick Nash", "Nick Patti", "Nick Starkel", "Nick Tronti", "Noah Johnson", 
    "Noah Vedral", "Parker McKinney", "Patrick O'Brien", "Perry Olsen", 
    "Peyton Ramsey", "Phil Jurkovec", "Quincy Patterson", "Re-al Mitchell", 
    "Rex Culpepper", "Rocky Lombardi", "Ryan Hilinski", "Sam Ehlinger", 
    "Sam Hartman", "Sam Howell", "Sean Chambers", "Sean Clifford", 
    "Shai Werts", "Shane Buechele", "Shane Illingworth", "Shawn Robinson", 
    "Skylar Thompson", "Spencer Petras", "Spencer Rattler", "Spencer Sanders", 
    "Stetson Bennett", "Stone Norton", "Taisun Phommachanh", "Tanner Mordecai", 
    "Tanner Morgan", "Tate Rodemaker", "Tate Whatley", "Taulia Tagovailoa", 
    "Terrance Gipson", "Terry Wilson", "Tevaka Tuioti", "Thomas MacVittie", 
    "TJ Finley", "Todd Centeio", "Tommy DeVito", "Trad Beatty", "Trae Self", 
    "Trent Wessel", "Trevor Lawrence", "Tyger Goslin", "Tyhier Tyler", 
    "Tyler Johnston", "Tyler Vitt", "Tyrrell Pigrome", "Warren Bryan", 
    "Westin Elliott", "Will Howard", "Will Koch", "Will Levis", "Will Rogers", 
    "Willie Taggart", "Xavier Arline", "Zac Thomas", "Zach Smith", 
    "Zach Wilson"), class = "factor"), Team = structure(c(11L, 88L, 
    14L, 56L, 54L, 16L), .Label = c("Air Force", "Alabama", "Appalachian State", 
    "Arkansas", "Arkansas State", "Army", "Auburn", "Baylor", "Boise State", 
    "Boston College", "BYU", "Campbell", "Central Arkasas", "Central Florida", 
    "Cincinnati", "Clemson", "Coastal Carolina", "Colorado State", 
    "Duke", "East Carolina", "Eastern Kentucky", "Florida", "Florida Atlantic", 
    "Florida International", "Florida State", "Fresno State", "Georgia", 
    "Georgia Southern", "Georgia State", "Georgia Tech", "Hawaii", 
    "Houston", "Houston Baptist", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", 
    "Iowa State", "Kansas", "Kansas State", "Kentucky", "Liberty", 
    "Louisiana-Lafayette", "Louisiana-Monroe", "Louisiana Tech", 
    "Louisville", "LSU", "Marshall", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", 
    "Memphis", "Miami", "Michigan", "Michigan State", "Middle Tenn. St", 
    "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Mississippi State", "Missouri", 
    "Navy", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Mexico", "North Carolina", 
    "North Carolina State", "North Texas", "Northwestern", "Notre Dame", 
    "Ohio State", "Oklahoma", "Oklahoma State", "Penn State", "Pittsburgh", 
    "Purdue", "Rice", "Rutgers", "San Diego State", "San Jose State", 
    "SMU", "South Alabama", "South Carolina", "South Florida", "Southern Miss", 
    "Stephen F. Austin", "Syracuse", "TCU", "Temple", "Tennessee", 
    "Texas", "Texas A&M", "Texas State", "Texas Tech", "Troy", "Tulane", 
    "Tulsa", "UAB", "UNC Charlotte", "UNLV", "Utah State", "UTEP", 
    "UTSA", "Vanderbilt", "Virginia", "Virginia Tech", "Wake Forest", 
    "West Virginia", "Western Kentucky", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"), class = "factor"), 
        G = c(7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L), Pts = c(242.2, 232.9, 227.1, 
        204.4, 203.1, 191.6), Pts.G = c(34.6, 38.8, 37.9, 34.1, 29, 
        31.9), COMP = c(144L, 132L, 167L, 134L, 144L, 135L), ATT = c(194L, 
        219L, 261L, 187L, 220L, 191L), YDS = c(2152L, 1650L, 2506L, 
        1846L, 1509L, 1833L), TD = c(19L, 20L, 21L, 18L, 11L, 17L
        ), INT = c(2L, 5L, 2L, 9L, 8L, 2L), YPA = c(11.09, 7.53, 
        9.6, 9.87, 6.86, 9.6), ATT.1 = c(41L, 78L, 48L, 67L, 139L, 
        29L), YDS.1 = c(150L, 284L, 118L, 281L, 476L, 71L), TD.1 = c(7L, 
        7L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `dput(head(dataset))` in your question?

Comment: Error in the title of the post is different from the error in the text?

Comment: @maloneypatr dput(head(dataset)) is not apart of the output when I run the code

Comment: add the output of `dput(head(dataset))` to the question

Comment: Taking a step back, what are you trying to predict?  Also, isn't one hot encoding is generally used like dummy variables?  If you're using this on the name field, you're going to have as many variables as you have names?